# How to assign peaks to mannose using H-NMR and COSY?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, carbohydrates

I did a H-NMR experiment with D-mannose in deuterated DMSO. I have difficulty assigning the peaks. I know doublet a is the anomeric centre C1 and that triplet f is the OH attached to C6. Doublets b,c,d and e also correspond with the OH groups. Looking at the COSY you see that a and b are next to each other which suggests that b is the OH on the anomeric carbon C1. However, COSY also shows that b and h are next to each other. How is this possible if with COSY you are only able to look 3 bonds further?
[image: nmr]

Comment: What resolution did you run the 1H NMR at ? Theres often a lot to be obtained from analysis of the peak splittings, but they're essentially non-existent here.

Comment: It's also way too concentrated which makes the peaks look ugly.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, in addition to the plot provided here (an overview, and already helpful for the signals labelled with a, and b) an expansion of 3--5 ppm (both along $f1$ and $f2$) with both the projection along the two axes would be beneficial for the attribution of the remaining cross signals.  And, you likely have access to the integration of the signals and their coupling constants, too; at least from a 1D $\ce{^1H}$-NMR spectrum of the same sample, which equally helps to re-attribute the signals properly.